# change my code to simple why in ionic code

Tags: ionic-framework

```
  `this.myTask.taskAssignee = event.detail.checked;`
  `this.myTask.taskCreated = event.detail.checked;`
 ` this.myTask.taskOverdue = event.detail.checked;`
 ` this.myTask.taskClosed = event.detail.checked;`
  `this.myTask.taskCancelled = event.detail.checked;`
  `this.myTask.taskCommentUpdate = event.detail.checked;`
 ` this.myTask.taskSubjectChanged = event.detail.checked;`
 ` this.myTask.taskInformationUpdated = event.detail.checked;`
  `this.myTask.taskDocumentUploaded = event.detail.checked;`
```

simple and one line of code and desivored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 for(i in this.myTask){
    this.myTask[i]=event.detail.checked;
    }
```